# Rtweets authentication issue

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I work with the fantastic Rtweet package for ad hoc analyses. I am teaching a workshop on some functionality and tried removing my authentication to show the entire process from start to finish by removing TWITTER_PAT from the my Renviron.

The result is that I try to authenticate from scratch, but receive the following error:

```
Requesting token on behalf of user...
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/maxwell1.rds', probable reason 'Permission denied'
```

I don't believe that file is even in that directory, according to my command prompt.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling rtweet. I've also restarted my computer. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: You do not have permission to write to this low level folder `Users`. You need to specify a location where you have the permission to write.

Comment: I never specified the path before though. How might I specify a path that I can access?

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik, I have the same question. How do I specify the path?

Comment: Perhaps you want to open a new question, make it reproducible even?